# Why if we put HandlerRegistration into a method then we can't removeHandler?

Tags: java, gwt

Ok, I have a lot of Checkboxes, when the program first runs, it will `addClickHandler` for all checkboxes, and when I reset the program I want to clear all the Handler.

This is the sample code;

```
 private HandlerRegistration countryHandlerReg=null;
 private HandlerRegistration postCodeHandlerReg=null;
 public void resetVariables(){
        if(postCodeHandlerReg!=null){
            postCodeHandlerReg.removeHandler();
        }
        if(countryHandlerReg!=null){
            countryHandlerReg.removeHandler();
        }

 }
 public void addClickHandlerForCheckBox(HandlerRegistration handlerReg, CheckBox myCheckBox){
        handlerReg=myCheckBox.addClickHandler(new MyClickHandler(myCheckBox));
 }
 public void showData(){
     resetVariables();
     addClickHandlerForCheckBox(postCodeHandlerReg, getView().getPostCodeCheckBox());
     addClickHandlerForCheckBox(countryHandlerReg, getView().getCountryCheckBox());
 }
```

There is a button to call the `showData()`

The above code doesn't work properly cos it could not run `.removeHandler()` so if i click the button 2 or 3 times then each checkbox will have 2 or 3 `MyClickHandler()`.

However, if I change the `showData()` like this without using method `addClickHandlerForCheckBox` then it runs ok:

```
public void showData(){
     resetVariables();
     postCodeHandlerReg= getView().getPostCodeCheckBox().addClickHandler(new MyClickHandler(getView().getPostCodeCheckBox()));
 ....
 }
```

so i think if i use `addClickHandlerForCheckBox` method then it can't remove the handler.

Do you know why? or i did something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do changes like this,it will remove the handlers

```
public HandlerRegistration addClickHandlerForCheckBox(CheckBox myCheckBox) {
 return myCheckBox.addClickHandler(new MyClickHandler(myCheckBox));
}
public void showData() {
  resetVariables();
  postCodeHandlerReg = addClickHandlerForCheckBox(postCode);
 countryHandlerReg = addClickHandlerForCheckBox(country);
}
```

Comment: thax u very much it' working, do u know how to removeHandler for a list of image?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643373/how-to-removehandler-for-a-listimage-in-java

Answer (score 0):

For a JCheckBox you can add and remove listeners like this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox();
    checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    ItemListener [] itemListeners = checkBox.getListeners(ItemListener.class);
    System.out.println(itemListeners.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < itemListeners.length; i++)
    {
        checkBox.removeItemListener(itemListeners[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(checkBox.getListeners(ItemListener.class).length);
}
```

It looks like you are using some custom classes though.  So if this example doesn't help, you may want to post the code for addClickHandler and removeHandler.

I assume you're keeping a list of Handlers on the CheckBox, so you could add some method like CheckBox.removeListeners that just clears the list.