# How to removeHandler for a List<Image> in Java?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
private HandlerRegistration filterImageHandlerReg=null;
public void resetVariables(){
    if(filterImageHandlerReg!=null){
         filterImageHandlerReg.removeHandler();
     }
}

public void callData(){
      resetVariables();
      for(int i=0; i<getView().getFilterImageList().size(); i++){
           Image filterImage=getView().getFilterImageList().get(i);
           filterImageHandlerReg= filterImage.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
                      System.out.println("test");
                 }
           });
      }
}
```

Thre is a button to `callData();` when I click that button 1 time, everything fine, it means when clicking image it will printout:

```
test
```

However, if i click button 2 time & then when click on image just 1 time, it will print out

```
test
test
```

it mean the Image was added multiple `ClickHandler();` & `filterImageHandlerReg.removeHandler();` doesn't work.

How to fix the problem?

Comment: You can replace that loop with for (Image filterImage : getView().getFilterImageList())

Comment: yes, but harder to see, & i need to use  i anyway

Comment: Then count it separately. If you were passed a linked list, you just wrote a method that runs in O(n^2) time.

Comment: no that not the point cos it just print out 2 time, my list has 20 images. I u said like that then it will prinout 20 "test", but it just print out 2 "test"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep a list of HandlerRegistration.

```
private List<HandlerRegistration> filterImageHandlerRegistrations=null;
public void resetVariables(){
    if(filterImageHandlerRegistrations!=null){
        for(HandlerRegistration handlerRegistration: filterImageHandlerRegistrations)
         handlerRegistration.removeHandler();
     }
}

    public void callData(){
          resetVariables();
          filterImageHandlerRegistrations=new ArrayList<HandlerRegistration>();
          for(int i=0; i<getView().getFilterImageList().size(); i++){
               Image filterImage=getView().getFilterImageList().get(i);

               filterImageHandlerRegistrations.add(filterImage.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
                          System.out.println("test");
                     }
               }));
          }
    }
```